# iOS: "An instance of SPAudioStreamingController is already in use."

Tags: iphone, ios10, spotify

i'm developping app using spotify-iOS-SDK, i have succesfully connect my app to Spotify and the audio is playing, but the problem is: When i close my PlaySongViewController, my app will be crash

```
"An instance of SPAudioStreamingController is already in use."
```

unless i stop my spotifyPlayer with this code after i logout

```
var spotifyPlayer: SPTAudioStreamingController? 

@IBAction func closeView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("close view")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.spotifyPlayer?.logout()
    invalidateTimers()
}

func audioStreamingDidLogout(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!) {
    print("after logout")
    try! self.spotifyPlayer?.stop()
}
```

The problem is continue if i close my ViewController directly before this code is working properly

```
        self.spotifyPlayer = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
        self.spotifyPlayer!.playbackDelegate = self
        self.spotifyPlayer!.delegate = self
        try! spotifyPlayer?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)

        self.spotifyPlayer!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
```

When i pick another song to open my PlaySongViewController again, it will be crashed with

```
"An instance of SPAudioStreamingController is already in use."
```

Another problem is when i try to log in with non-premium account, when i open PlaySongViewController, it will show "Spotify Premium Required" and when i close my PlaySongViewController and open another PlaySongViewController to play another song, it will be crashed again with the 'already in use' error

Can i bypass this code if i have start my spotifyPlayer?

```
try! spotifyPlayer?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
```

Or Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are two things I am seeing here:

```
try! spotifyPlayer?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
```

That should be a `do` and `catch`, if you look at the full signature for the start signature it states that it will throw errors. Instead make sure to catch errors when you can.

```
  do {
    try self.spotifyPlayer?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
  } catch {
    print("Failed to start with clientId")
  }
```

It is important not force a `try` but instead [handle errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

> You use a do-catch statement to handle errors by running a block of
>   code. If an error is thrown by the code in the do clause, it is
>   matched against the catch clauses to determine which one of them can
>   handle the error.

Additionally on the `SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()` is a property that is worth checking before the `do` and `catch` which is `player?.loggedIn` you can use this method to check before you attempt to call `login`, I've put an example of this in the singleton's `login` method below.

```
/** Returns `YES` if the receiver is logged into the Spotify service, otherwise `NO`. */
open var loggedIn: Bool { get }
```

Secondly you might be better off creating a [singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID177) to handle all the logic of playing music that the View controller interfaces with so you don't end up with multiple view controllers trying to use the same `spotifyPlayer` and call `start` when it isn't necessary.

```
class MusicPlayer:  {
  static let shared = MusicPlayer()
  fileprivate let player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()

  override init() {
    player?.playbackDelegate = self
    player?.delegate = self
  }

  func login() {
     if player?.loggedIn { return }
     do {
       try self.spotifyPlayer?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
     } catch {
       print("Failed to start with clientId")
     }
  }
}
```

and then in the view controller link to `MusicPlayer.shared`.

Comment: i'm still confused about the Singleton Stuff, i build app like musixmatch, how can i handle my lyrics in my MusicPlayer class if i must handle my lyric in my PlaySongViewController? Anyway, if i put player delegate in MusicPlayer, i must put audioStreamingdidLogin func etc in MusicPlayer class instead in my view controller?

Comment: You don't have to use a Singleton if you don't want to. The do and catch block should be enough in itself. But yes, to your question the delegate methods would be in music player. I'm not sure how your coffee is currently structured well enough to go into detail with how displaying lyrics would look.

Comment: yes, the do and catch lyric works well, i try to use try? too and it works fine because it can gives null, and for the second, i think won't use singleton for now. Thank you very much for your help & your input , really help.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Comment: @calvinsugianto I've added one last piece above regarding the property on the player, `loggedIn`.